# change color of datatable filter dropdown box

Tags: css, r, shiny, datatable

Hello.

I would like to change the color of this dropdown box which appears for numeric filters.
[image]

Sample code:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars,filter="top")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to modify the suitable CSS on the `ui` function:

```r
ui <- basicPage(
    h2("The mtcars data"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
    tags$style(type = "text/css",
               ".noUi-connect {background: red;}")
)
```

[image]

**Update**

As explained in the comments, you can see in the next image (open it to see larger) where is the CSS modified to get a dark red where you want (in the right column of left window above is the `element.style` to which my comment below refers). The issue I am not able to solve is how to modify that tag (the shadowed one at the left) ` without a class or an id, with CSS or Shiny.

[image]

Comment: Hello iago. For some reason my original comment was deleted but I was referring to the color of the white box that contains the slider and numbers. How would I go about changing that? Thanks.

Comment: I had seen the comment. Since then I am trying to get an answer without success. In fact, I have identified the part of html code where is specified backround-color = white, but I cannot get it modified with CSS on shiny.

Comment: @niceguy Finally I could not find a solution. It is modified in a div tag as an "`element.style`, which indicates styles that are directly assigned to the element, such as via the style tag (<input style="" />)." (https://groups.google.com/g/firebug/c/yncABF66Eck). That is, there is no class or id to modify that tag. All what I tried did not work. I am not sure if anything can be done. I update the answer with an image with the detail.